# the view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

For testing my form loggin, in the view index I return a dictionary. When I clicked on the submit button I receive this message error :

```
The view accueil.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Where I made a mistake?

```
def index(request):
formConnex = ConnexionForm()
if request.method=='POST':
    formConnex =ConnexionForm(request.POST)
    if formConnex.is_valid():
        envoi = True
        surnom = formConnex.cleaned_data['surnom']
        password = formConnex.cleaned_data['passeword']
        formConnex = ConnexionForm()   
        dicInfoCon =    {
            'surnom_key':email,
            'password_key':password,
            'envoi_key':envoi
        }

        return render(request,'accueil/index.html',dicInfoCon)
else:
    envoi = False
    formConnex = ConnexionForm() 
    return render(request, 'accueil/index.html', 'formConnex_Key':formConnex})
```

Comment: maybe it in case `formConnex.is_valid()` is `False`. Can you check it?

Comment: How can i checked that? By printing print(formConnex.is_valid)? And in the terminal i will see the value(true or false)?

Comment: Yes, or even better: try to use a real debugger.

Comment: are `return` and `render(...)` on different lines ? move render next to return.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is when the form is not valid. It does not return anything from function. To be exact:

```
if request.method=='POST':
    formConnex =ConnexionForm(request.POST)  # Please use snake_case
    if formConnex.is_valid():
        envoi = True
        surnom = formConnex.cleaned_data['surnom']
        password = formConnex.cleaned_data['passeword']
        formConnex = ConnexionForm()   
        dicInfoCon = {
            'surnom_key':email,
            'password_key':password,
            'envoi_key':envoi
        }

        return render(request,'accueil/index.html',dicInfoCon)
  # Here should be an else block with how the view should handle if the form is not valid
```

So, you can update the method like this(I have added some refactoring):

```
def index(request):
    formConnex = ConnexionForm(request.POST or None) # Please use snake_case, according to PEP-8 style guide
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if formConnex.is_valid():
            envoi = True
            surnom = formConnex.cleaned_data['surnom']
            password = formConnex.cleaned_data['passeword']
            dicInfoCon = {
                'surnom_key': email,
                'password_key': password,
                'envoi_key': envoi
            }
            return render(request, 'accueil/index.html', dicInfoCon)

    return render(request, 'accueil/index.html', {'formConnex_Key':formConnex})
```

Comment: It would be great if the cause of the down vote is explained. I would be happy to improve my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply that your final return line is indented too far. Move it back one indent, so that it also catches the case where request is POST but the form is not valid.

Comment: All the indents was good. During i copied the code in the editor, the indent was not respected.